# NgRx problem: effect doesn't call my api endpoint

Tags: angular, ngrx

I have a problem with NgRx, my action calls my effect but the effect doesn't call my api and I don't know why in api everything is fine because I go to the home page and without ngrx I successfully create movie.

I have this action in my actions file:

```
export const createMovie = createAction(`${moviesDomain} Create Movie`, props<{model: CreateMovie}>);
```

And this is my effect:

```
onCreateMovies$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(createMovie),
    mergeMap(async movie => {            
        this.moviesService.createMovie(movie.model)
    })
    ),
    {
        dispatch: false
    }
  );
```

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't reach the backend and your issue isn't that you don't update the frontend?

Comment: Yes, I am sure.

Comment: Have you called createMovie outside of NgRx, does it work?

Comment: Yes, it's work outside of NgRx.

Comment: the issue is that you have set dispatch as false

Comment: How would be with dispatch as true ?

Comment: I receive errors if dispatch is not false.

Comment: @VimalPatel dispatch false should not hinder the request, but simply fire and forget

Comment: @Danail the error you see is that you need to return an action if dispatch is true. Are you sure the effect is even called? Did you register the Effects? (https://ngrx.io/guide/effects#registering-root-effects)

Comment: dispatch false is there for performing side-effect. you just need to return from the service call to make it. Please try it it should work

Answer (score 0):

Mergemap needs to return an inner observable

```
onCreateMovies$ = createEffect(() => this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType(createMovie),
    mergeMap(async movie => {       
    //      
       return this.moviesService.createMovie(movie.model)
    })
    ),
    {
        dispatch: false
    }
  );
```